# C# Get Array Length Hack (Unsafe)

Tags: c#, arrays

I was trying to understand the generated instructions for C# array's length operation. While playing with pointers I realized this. If we get the pointer to the array's first element and subtract 2 from it and dereference that pointer, we get the array length. I am curious if there are any expert C# developers who can enlighten me on this matter.

Here is the code. Following code does not throw any exceptions.

```
using System;

namespace TestArrayLength
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AssertLength(new []    {1,2,3,4,5});
            AssertLength(new []    {-1,-2,-3,-2323,33454325,456456,54354});
            AssertLength(new []    {0});
            AssertLength(new int[] {});
            AssertLength(new []    {5,7,1,-4576,4345,8888,9678,5,5,8459});
        }

        private static unsafe void AssertLength(int[] arr)
        {
            if (GetLength(arr) != arr.Length)
                throw new Exception("Not Equal!");
        }

        private static unsafe int GetLength(int[] arr)
        {
            fixed (int* ptr = arr)
                return ptr != null ? ptr[-2] : 0;
        }

        // Edit (Generic version)
        private static unsafe int GetLength<T>(T[] arr) where T : unmanaged
        {
            fixed (T* ptr = arr)
                return ptr == null 
                        ? 0 
                        : ((int*)ptr)[-(sizeof(IntPtr) / sizeof(int))];
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just don't do that. Btw. it fails with a 32 bit build.

Comment: I know I shouldn't do that in real production code. I was just trying to understand the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'In single-dimensional arrays, the array elements are preceded by a length field that indicates the capacity of the array.  One sets this field when one creates the array, and one cannot change it for the lifetime of the array.'  This is from Don Box's book ['Essential .NET Volume 1: the Common Language Runtime'](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-NET-Microsoft-Development-Paperback/dp/0201734117/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=essential%20.net%20don%20box&qid=1595795401&sr=8-1).  I think that what you are doing only works because your arrays contain integers (32 bits) and you are on a 64-bit machine: p[-2] takes you 64 bits before the first array element, which is where the length is stored.  In general as @György Kőszeg says, just don't do that.  There's a perfectly good Length property, which will safely return the right value.  That book is quite good for immense detail on how the CLR works by the way.

Comment: You are right, I think this fixes the problem:
`private static unsafe int GetLength<T>(T[] arr) where T : unmanaged
 {
 fixed (T* ptr = arr)
     return ptr == null 
               ? 0 
                : ((int*)ptr)[-(sizeof(IntPtr) / sizeof(int))]; }`.